# Is split what I want to use here or pop?

Tags: perl

I found out something strange about `split`. I guess it will not parse blank content until there is something at the end.

I have a string that splits at a comma.  However, when there are repeated delimiters at the end, they will not be added to the array until there is something at the end like so:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "ABC,123,,,,,,"; # just ABC and 123
#my $str = "ABC,123,,,,,,this"; # now it shows the blanks.
my @elems = split ',', $str;
print Dumper \@elems;
```

Any other ways, such as regex? Or should I trick the array and then `pop` the last content out?

Comment: Well, it looks like you should be using a CSV parser, such as [Text::CSV_XS](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS). :)

Answer (score 14):

You can specify a negative LIMIT:

```
my $str = "ABC,123,,,,,,";
my @elems = split ',', $str, -1;
```

From [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> If LIMIT is **negative**, it is treated as if it were instead arbitrarily
>   large; as many fields as possible are produced.
>
> If LIMIT is **omitted** (or, equivalently, **zero**), then it is usually
>   treated as if it were instead negative but with the exception that
>   trailing empty fields are stripped

`Dumper` output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'ABC',
          '123',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          ''
        ];
```

Comment: Note that `split` acts like it does by default because it saves you several scalar worth of space. Accessing the list value by index gets you the same result because Perl will extend the array as necessary and give you back the undef value (which converts to the empty string). Thus, waiting until you need to access those fields is an intended optimization.

Answer (score -1):

For reference: a *regular expression* can assist in filling an array

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str;
$str = 'ABC,123,,,,,,';         # just ABC and 123
#$str = 'ABC,123,,,,,,this';    # now it shows the blanks

my @elems = $str =~ /([^,]*),?/g;

print Dumper \@elems;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'ABC',
          '123',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          ''
        ];
```